# Accessing Different variables in vb using Me.Controls key word

Tags: vb.net

```
 Dim name1,name2,name3
 Dim i
 for i = 1 to 3
 Me.Controls("name" & i) = i
 next
```

Whenever i try to execute this code i get a error. What could be the issue ?

With regards,

nandgate.

Comment: "Object reference not set to any instance of an object" is the error message i get. name1, name2 and name3 are 3 variables declared in the code, They are not controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign an `Integer` to a member of a collection that holds `Control`s, perhaps in addition to not having controls named `name1`, `name2` or `name3` on the form. If it helps with understanding, you're not accessing the three variables of type `Object` that you've declared in the first statement at all: the `Me.Controls` property retrieves a collection of the controls in the current form (assuming this code is somewhere in a form class).

You seem to be missing a few concepts, including strong typing and the structure of common classes in WinForms such as `Control`. I'd suggest you start with the official MSDN [walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229601.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are interested in getting a control say `TextBox1` and assign some value to its `Text` property. Following example may help you on this:

#### Untested sample code:

```
 Dim name1,name2,name3
 Dim i
 for i = 1 to 3
   Dim ctrl() as Control = Me.Controls.Find("TextBox" & i, true)   ' Find control in all children controls
   if(ctrl isNot nothing andAlso ctrl.Length > 0) then ' if there is a control found
        Ctype(ctrl(0), Textbox).Text = i   ' Assign its text property to ith value.
   end if 
 next
```